# Windows 10 - b150i - USB lost after update

Tags: windows, windows-10, usb, windows-update

This is the third time I have installed windows 10 :(

After installing windows 10, everything is working as intended.

Apply windows updates -> all USB ports stop working (only once windows is booted).

The USB ports still work in the bios and some of the windows repair utilities (command prompt, but no safe modes).

I read somewhere on some forum something about chipset drivers but then I got scared. My motherboard is the b150i.

**What I have**

- boot up command prompt (force boot to fail via flicking power switch, it's one of the only windows repair options that does anything)
- un-elevated command prompt in boot up (I added a startup.bat to `Start Menu\Programs\Startup` to run commands like killing steam, ipconfig, etc)
- network over wifi

I was hoping to gain access to remote desktop, but no registry entries seem to be giving me access, and I don't think I can install anything due to UAC and SmartScreen Filter.

Does anyone know what is up here? Is it possible to force an uninstall of the usb drivers from the boot up command prompt? Is it possible to turn on remote desktop from the boot up command prompt? I think once I have remote desktop working I will be able to continue on debugging myself.

Comment: *"I read somewhere on some forum something about chipset drivers but then I got scared."*  We are always glad to help, but can you please elaborate on that statement?  Did you install new chipset drivers?  If not, why would you be scared of doing that?

Comment: @Run5k I didn't install the chipset drivers, I was reading it on my way to work. I really was hoping I wouldn't have to do that when I got home that night

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was trivial, the motherboard already came with bluetooth, adding the USB bluetooth adapter did something bad upon reboot.

Solution: check your mobo specs before plugging random stuff into it